# Hashtag in URL for show div base on compare ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, hash, hashtag

Ok, I will try explain my question.
I need to add class ".active" into already existing class ".jobs", when URL have hashtag same as ID, inside tag with class ".jobs".

Here is working code just for one compare:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hashVal = window.location.hash.split("#")[1];
    if(hashVal == 'programmer') {
        $("#programmer").addClass('active');
    }
});
```

In practice:
Someone will come to website www.domain.tld/jobs#programmer then I need compare "#programmer" from ULR with all existing IDs in all `<div>` tags, which also have class ".jobs", and if there will be someone with class="jobs" and also id="programmer", I need to add into this `<div>` tag class "active".

**Is there a way to make jQuery code more variable?** Like without having add comparison for each ID name? and also I need to move browser windows on position, where div with that ID it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var hashVal = window.location.hash.split("#")[1];    
if($('#'+hashVal).hasClass('jobs')) $('#'+hashVal).addClass('active');
```